# How can I add folders and files back to git tracking after git rm command?

Tags: git, github, version-control, repository

I removed a folder from my git repo by mistake with `git rm` commands.
Now, whatever modification I make in that fold will not show up in `git status`
How can I make git track this missing folder again?  Thanks.

Comment: If you haven't committed the effects of `git rm that/dir/` : run `git restore -s HEAD -SW that/dir/`

Comment: Note that Git never stores any folders at all, and therefore doesn't track them either (actually it's kind of the other way around: it's unable to track them and therefore doesn't store them). The only thing Git stores are *files* and Git will create folder names on the fly as needed. That is, a commit might have `path/to/file` stored in it as a *file name* (complete with forward slashes); Git will make `path` and `to` if/when necessary to store `file` in `to` in `path` as your OS requires.

Comment: None of this matters too much as long as there's at least one file in `path/to` so that you can `git add path/to/file`. It's when `path/to` exists, but is empty, that this shows up: since Git only stores *files* you have to create at least one file in there, such as `.gitignore`, so that you can `git add path/to/.gitignore` for instance. (Some people use `.gitkeep` as a fake file here, but I prefer `.gitignore`.)

Answer (score 1):

`git rm` alone would not prevent git status to show differences in the folder.

Check if you have a `.gitignore` rule which would explain why git status does not work in that folder.

```
git check-ignore -v -- yourFolder/aFile_inside_that_folder
```

If it displays a `.gitignore` filename and a line, you will know why you don't see anything.
You can then delete that rule, and `git status` should work again.

---

From the [OP Jim Wang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10881963/jim-wang)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73188973/how-can-i-add-folders-and-files-back-to-git-tracking-after-git-rm-command/73190474#comment129299660_73190474)

> I tried the command you provided, and the output is:
>
> ```
> fatal: Pathspec 'myFolder/setup.sh' is in submodule 'higherleveFolder/myFolder'.
> ```
>
> At the very beginning, "`myFolder`" is a separate repo I cloned inside the original repo.
> Could you tell me how to clean up everything and make git track "`myFolder`" again?

If you have a `.gitmodules` in the main repository root folder, try what [I recommended in 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/6309):

```bash
0. mv a/submodule a/submodule_tmp

1. git submodule deinit -f -- higherleveFolder/myFolder
2. rm -rf .git/modules/higherleveFolder/myFolder
3. git rm --cached higherleveFolder/myFolder
# Note: higherleveFolder/myFolder (no trailing slash)
```

From there, you can `git add`, `commit` and `push` `higherleveFolder/myFolder` content.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance.  I forgot what operations I did (i.e. git rm and others) to make git stop tracking this folder.  I tried the command you provided, and the output is:  fatal: Pathspec 'myFolder/setup.sh' is in submodule 'higherleveFolder/myFolder'.   At the very beginning,  "myFolder" is a separate repo I cloned inside the original repo.  I am not an expert of Git but I tried a lot of random operations which caused a mess in my repo ... Could you tell me how to clean up everything and make git track "myFolder" again? Thanks.

Comment: @JimWang Thank you for your feedback. I have edited the answer to address your comment.